# Replace values of specific pattern with 'NaN' in csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file  similar to this but with about 155,000 rows with years from 1910-2010 and 83 different station id's:

```
station_id  year    month   element    1     2     3   4   5    6
216565       2008      7    SNOW       0TT    0     0   0   0   0 
216565       2008      8    SNOW        0     0T    0   0   0   0 
216565       2008      9    SNOW        0     0     0   0   0   0
```

and I want to replace any value  that has a pattern of a number and then one letter or a number and then two letter with NaN.

My desired output then is:

```
station_id  year    month   element    1     2     3   4   5    6
216565       2008      7    SNOW       NaN    0     0   0   0   0 
216565       2008      8    SNOW        0     NaN   0   0   0   0 
216565       2008      9    SNOW        0     0     0   0   0   0
```

I have tried to use:

`replace=df.replace([r'[0-9] [A-Z]'], ['NA'])
replace2=replace.replace([r'[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'], ['NA'])`

I was hoping by using the pattern of [0-9] [A-Z] would take care of a number and just one letter and then [0-9][A-Z][A-Z] would replace any cells with 2 letters but the file stays the exact same even though no errors are returned.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to do this?  You could just interpret them as NaN instead.

Comment: I needed it because I didn't know interpreting them as NaN was an option.  I should say that the real csv isn't filled in with all zeros like the example above, there are real values besides zero I still need to keep.

Comment: So you're working with a CSV file?  Could you include that in your question?

Comment: correct, and edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pandas method [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) to do this. You'll set `convert_numeric` to `True`

> convert_numeric : if True attempt to coerce to numbers (including
>   strings), non-convertibles get NaN

```
>>> df
   station_id  year  month element    1   2  3  4  5  6
0      216565  2008      7    SNOW  0TT   0  0  0  0  0
1      216565  2008      8    SNOW    0  0T  0  0  0  0
2      216565  2008      9    SNOW    0   0  0  0  0  0
>>> df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
   station_id  year  month element   1   2  3  4  5  6
0      216565  2008      7    SNOW NaN   0  0  0  0  0
1      216565  2008      8    SNOW   0 NaN  0  0  0  0
2      216565  2008      9    SNOW   0   0  0  0  0  0
```

---

If you wish to go the route of using [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), you need to modify your call.

```
>>> df
   station_id  year  month element    1   2  3  4  5  6
0      216565  2008      7    SNOW  0TT   0  0  0  0  0
1      216565  2008      8    SNOW    0  0T  0  0  0  0
2      216565  2008      9    SNOW    0   0  0  0  0  0
>>> df1.replace(value=np.nan, regex=r'[0-9][A-Z]+')
   station_id  year  month element    1    2  3  4  5  6
0      216565  2008      7    SNOW  NaN    0  0  0  0  0
1      216565  2008      8    SNOW    0  NaN  0  0  0  0
2      216565  2008      9    SNOW    0    0  0  0  0  0
```

This also requires that you import numpy (`import numpy as np`)

Comment: this is great and so much easier than what I was trying!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace` doesn't do regexes. Use the `re` module instead (assuming df is a string):

```
import re
re.sub(r'[0-9][A-Z]+', 'NaN', df)
```

returns:

```
station_id  year    month   element    1     2     3   4   5    6
216565       2008      7    SNOW       NaN    0     0   0   0   0 
216565       2008      8    SNOW        0     NaN    0   0   0   0 
216565       2008      9    SNOW        0     0     0   0   0
```

However, you would be better off letting e.g. Pandas or np.genfromtxt handle the invalid values automatically.

Comment: It expects a string or buffer with this and I have a DataFrame, would I need to convert to string first then with this method?

Comment: That would probably work, but it would be better to use pandas or numpy to handle the invalid values when you create the DataFrame or ndarray from a file. Is this possible?

Comment: You will have to excuse my illiteracy with this I have only been working with python and pandas for about 2 weeks now so I am not sure if it is possible.  The response from Andy seemed to have worked though but I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @spotter I think @xnx is interpreting your data as a string output. pandas does have a [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method. I've updated my answer to also include how it would work with `replace` as well.

Comment: I see how I got off track trying to use replace now, both methods are very helpful though, and again, many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
from re import sub

string = "station_id year month element 1 2 3 4 5 6 216565 2008 7 SNOW 0TT 0 0 0 0 0 216565 2008 8 SNOW 0 0T 0 0 0 0 216565 2008 9 SNOW 0 0 0 0 0 0"

string = sub(r'\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1,2}', 'NaN', string)

print string

# station_id year month element 1 2 3 4 5 6 216565 2008 7 SNOW NaN 0 0 0 0 0 216565 2008 8 SNOW 0 NaN 0 0 0 0 216565 2008 9 SNOW 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: What happened to the dataframe?